Why do some journals request that headings are not included in figures?
For some journals the guidelines for authors recommend that headings be removed from figures. However, by removing headings the figures are more difficult to be interpreted as they require reference to the caption or the text. Is this simply related to historical pre-digital printing practices ?

One reason might be that the journal would prefer not to have a different font in graphics than in the text. Also, text within graphics is not searchable, not selectable, and cannot be read aloud by screenreaders for sight-impaired readers. (All these are just reasons I could think of; I have no idea what reasons a journal would give, so this is not an answer, merely speculation.)

Are you sure the guidelines say to remove the headings completely? I only know guidelines saying the headings should be regular text (anchored to the figures, of course).

What do you mean "headings"? Captions? Like "Figure 1: blah."

@AzorAhai-him- I assume because OP also speaks of captions, the heading is the heading on top of a graph (which e.g. says "hours spent per basket as a function of water temperature"), which IMO is perfectly fine to put in the caption instead.

@Sursula I would call those "titles" (just trying to clarify). I suppose I was confused by Mr. Miyagi's comment, because I've never tried to make "titles" "regular text."

The information that would go in a figure title is information that should be in the caption anyway, so including a title is redundant. Not using titles also makes it easier to have a relatively consistent "look" across different papers in the journal, and reduces the problem of having inconsistent font sizes when the figure is resized for layout reasons. Including titles either makes the figures take up more space or makes them more cluttered. For print journals, space matters. And some people just prefer the aesthetics of figures without titles.

It seems to me that the consistency and font sizing issues would also apply to plot legends but I've never seen instructions asking to remove those.

@anyon Leaving titles off doesn't eliminate that problem, but it reduces it. The issue of redundancy is probably a bigger factor anyway.
